# Bubble chart - how to disable or hide all values below a Y-Axis value dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

How is it possible to disable all value below a particular given Y-Axis value, so every point in a Bubble Chart is going to be disabled under this Y-Value. I only want to disable these values, not delete them, because I need to show that disabled points later on.

I only saw approaches with deleting the points, the bubble points getting re-sized in the chart, which I don't want to. I want to fix the size of the bubbles in the chart, regardless to the other bubble points.

I am working with Visual Studio Windows Form Application.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you can 1) set the Y-Axis Minimum ar 2) make the color of those Poits Transparent.

Comment: @TaW thank you for your answer. It works if I set my Y-Axis Maximum, but the chart also re-sizes. I would like to have a static Y-Axis, but only disable the Points.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'disable the points'? I really don't understand, other than making them invisible..

Comment: @TaW sorry, disabling is maybe the wrong word for that. just hide them or make them invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataPoints` don't have a `Visible` property.

To make all `DataPoints` with some condition invisible you set their `Color` to `Transparent`.

Here is an example:

```
foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
    foreach (DataPoint dp in series.Points)
         dp.Color = dp.YValues[0] < 0 ? Color.Transparent : series.Color;
```